# How to send message to followers-only Twitch chat?

Tags: python, websocket, irc, twitch

I use this code:

```
import socket
import socks

channel = 'some_channel'
name = 'some_nickname'
oauthtoken = 'oauth:sometoken123456'
message = 'hello chat'

s = socks.socksocket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("irc.chat.twitch.tv" , 6667))
s.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(oauthtoken).encode())
s.send("NICK {}\r\n".format(name).encode())
join = "JOIN #" + channel + "\r\n"
s.send(join.encode())
message = "PRIVMSG #" + channel + " :" + message + "\r\n"
s.send(message.encode())

resp = s.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
print(resp)
```

For a regular char this code works perfectly.
If I send a message to a regular chat and to a follower-only chat, I get the same response:

```
:tmi.twitch.tv 001 some_nickname :Welcome, GLHF!
:tmi.twitch.tv 002 some_nickname :Your host is tmi.twitch.tv
:tmi.twitch.tv 003 some_nickname :This server is rather new
:tmi.twitch.tv 004 some_nickname :-
:tmi.twitch.tv 375 some_nickname :-
:tmi.twitch.tv 372 some_nickname :You are in a maze of twisty passages, all alike.
:tmi.twitch.tv 376 some_nickname :>
```

What do I need to change in code to send a message to a follower-only chat?

Comment: What research have you done so far? What options have you considered?

Comment: @MadPhysicist I'll tell you the situation in more detail: I have a user account A and B, I also have a Twitch channel C and D. C has a chat only for followers, D has a regular chat open to everyone. A follows channel C, B does not follow channel C. When I send a message to the chat of channel C from accounts A and B, the message does not come to the chat and I receive the same response from the server for both accounts specified in the question. When I send a message to the channel D chat from accounts A and B, the message comes to the chat and I receive the same response from the server.

Comment: I tried sending data as bytes, it didn't help. I read Twitch's IRC documentation, it says nothing about follower-only chats (or I couldn't find it, which I doubt). I used several other people's scripts from GitHub, same problem there.